# 1D FFT MATLAB results are different from FFTW in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, fftw

I have the MATLAB code:

```
Nx = 10; 
Ny = 10; 
Lx = 2*pi; 
ygl = -cos(pi*(0:Ny)/Ny)'; %Gauss-Lobatto chebyshev points 
x  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
%make mesh
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(x,ygl); 
A = 2*pi / Lx;
u = sin( (2*pi / Lx) * X);
uh = fft(u)
```

This gives the following output:

```
0    6.4656   10.4616   10.4616    6.4656    0.0000   -6.4656  -10.4616  -10.4616   -6.4656
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000         0         0         0
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000
         0         0         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0         0
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000         0         0         0
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0         0
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000
         0    0.0000         0         0    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000         0         0         0
```

And the C++ code using FFTW:

```
static const int nx = 10;
static const int ny = 10; 
static const int nyk = ny/2 + 1;

double Lx = 2 * M_PI;
double A = (2 * M_PI)/Lx;

    double *XX;
    XX = (double*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
    memset(XX, 42, (nx*(ny+1))* sizeof(double)); 
    

    double *YY;
    YY = (double*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
    memset(YY, 42, (nx*(ny+1))* sizeof(double)); 

    double *u;
    u = (double*) fftw_malloc((((ny+1)*nx))*sizeof(double)); 
    

    fftw_complex *uh; 
    uh = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(((ny+1)*nyk)*sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    memset(uh, 42, ((ny+1)*nyk)* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 


    
    for(int i = 0; i< nx+1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
            XX[i + (ny+1)*j] = (j)*2*M_PI/nx; 
            YY[i + (ny+1)*j] = -1. * cos(((i) * M_PI )/ny); 
            u[i + (ny+1)*j] = sin(A * XX[i + (ny+1)*j]);
        
        }   
    
    }
fftw_plan r2c1; 
r2c1 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(nx , &u[0], &uh[0], FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(r2c1);
fftw_destroy_plan(r2c1);
fftw_cleanup();
//print uh
```

This give the output:

```
(0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
 (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),  (0.0000,0.0000),
```

Why are these two results are NOT matching?? I understand there are some differences between FFT in MATLAB and C++ but this is a simple 1D FFT and it's WAY off than the MATLAB results.

NOTE: I added the results of MATLAB and C++ for comparison ad requested by someone in the comments.

Comment: you dont show us how different they are. so maybe it is 1. a floating point accuracy difference 2. a bug in your code (you dont use the X,Y meshgrid line, so why do you have it? 3. an fftshift operation that you are missing in matlab, etc....

Comment: @bla I can post the results to help show how different the outputs. I am using ``X`` from meshgrid to define my test function ``u``.

Comment: Stupid question: did you plot your results? Maybe it's just the scaling.

Comment: @Fr93 oh I didn't really try that actually maybe I should

Comment: @dmedine how am I running a 2D FFT in MATLAB? Also, I tried looking at 2D fft in c++ and that too is not matching. Yeah sorry originally u is a function of YY and XX, but I thought for simplicity I will reduce it to XX only for now.

Comment: Also, you are doing a very strange thing with your pointers in the call to fftw. `u` and `uh` are already pointers so you don't have to dereference the first element in the array. You can just use them directly: `r2c1 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(nx , u, uh, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`

Comment: @Jamie, if your input to `fft` (the Matlab function) is a matrix, `fft` will do a DFT on each column of the matrix. `u` is a matrix.

Comment: " if your input to fft (the Matlab function) is a matrix, fft will do a DFT on each column of the matrix. u is a matrix." I though I was doing similar thing in C++?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried both: ``fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`` and ``fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d`` not of which is matching the MATLAB output.

Comment: Oh I see, now using ``r2c1 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(nx , ne0, ne0k, FFTW_FORWARD);`` is returning ``Segmentation fault`` which means something is out of bound.

Comment: @dmedine a 1D FFT of each column is not a 2D FFT. It is a 1D FFT of each column. I agree that the C++ code does a single FFT, it needs to be looped over the columns to match MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo what do you mean looped over the columns? how?

Comment: d'oh! I have been giving terrible advice.

Comment: @Jamie MATLAB’s FFT does a 1D FFT on each column of the matrix. FFTW’s 1D FFT just does a single FFT. You need to point it at each of the columns in turn, in a loop.

Comment: I see, but I wasn't sure how to index that really.  Would you mind sharing an example

Comment: just adding 2 cents. if Matlab , a commercial product that has matured over 20 years for scientific computations  is doing FFT, check yourself and the documentation on what are you doing.  Why am i seeing a 2D array here at all? start with a 1D example please. just one vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by taking the FFT of each columns as someone suggested in the comments:

```
   { 
    cplx_buffer out = my_fftw_allocate_cplx(nyk, nx);
    fftw_execute(fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(1, &in.rows, in.cols, in.a, &in.rows, in.cols, 1, out.a, &in.rows, out.cols, 1, FFTW_ESTIMATE));
    std::cout << "DFT of input, column-wise\n"; print_matrix(out);
  }
```